# Фоновой рисунок перед блоком

Tags: css, css3

Нужно сделать чтобы девушка как бы держала div блок руками,

```
background-image: url(/img/bgm.png) !important;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
padding-top: 187px;
background-position: top;
```

Всё верно, но рисунок на фоне, видны рамки блока поверх картинки, как сделать картинку на передний план

Comment: Поиграйте с `z-index`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй псевдоэлемент :before с абсолютным позиционированием, в него вставляй девушку.

Comment: Быстрый пример https://jsfiddle.net/odc7ruz9/